# Выполнение действий во время набора в EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Мне нужно выполнять определенное действие во время начала набора текста в EditText, а также после набора каждых N символов. Как возможно это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен `TextWatcher`. Например примерно так:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onTextChanged with text: " + charSequence);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
});
```